# Match sources using python/astropy

Tags: python, scikit-learn, astropy, astronomy

Basically I have 2 lists which contain sourcename, RightAscension and Declination.

I have written most of the code with classes that also read my files and I have created coordinates.Skycoord with RA and DECs from bot files. But I have a problem when it comes to the most important thing that I want to do.

Specifically, I want to add sources on list1 lets say. List2 is bigger than list1 and also contains same sources as list1. I want to add the sources from list2 that do not have the same name as the ones in list1 and their MAX_SEP (separation) is less than 1 arcsec. Then I need to add those sources into list1.

I tried some for loops mostly but it was taking too much time.

Comment: Show some examples of what your data look like -- it will be much easier for people to understand. For example, show your input data and the sort of output you want. Normally people also show their current code, and explain how its output is not what they want. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask